# Google Oauth2 Prevent duplicate email address?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-oauth, google-openidconnect

I created a website for an organization where users can log in with there `gsuite` accounts from `google`, let say, user `john` logged in using `john@doe.com`, and do his `todos`.now imagine  user `john` left an organization and another new user called `john`, get the new google account called `john@doe.com`, when new john gets logged in using google how to check weather its a new gmail or old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OpenID Connect, which you should if you need the Authentication of the user and this type of detail, then the combination of the "iss" and the "sub" claim within the access_token are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: sub claim is enough itseems.